# PMD - Eclipse plugin - Not testing against any rules

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, code-analysis, pmd

I'm using Eclipse Juno (Service Release 1) and installed the latest version of the PMD plugin from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/ 
I can configure the plugin and select which rules should be executed but unfortunately, no rules are checked. If I click on "Check code" in the PMD submenu, a dialog pops up saying "Checking with 0 out of xxx rules"

What has to be configured and where to enable the functionality? On the console PMD is running fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Preferences -> PMD (please do not search PMD on search bar then you can not find the rule configuration try to find by scrolling each preference).
2. Select the required rules.
3. Click apply & OK (It will re-build the rules)
4. Now right click on the code and select PMD-> code Check

Comment: I am using Eclipse Oxygen on Mac with JDK1.8. Installed the newest PMD from marketplace. I don't see PMD from Preferences-->PMD. Though I can right click and enable PMD(but not working).

Answer (score 2):

Check if PMD is enabled on Project Properties.

Comment: Also check if rules are enabled on Window/Preferences/PMD/Rule Configuration

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As mentioned before, I unchecked and checked again all rules but without any success. Also, PMD is enabled in the project properties.

Comment: You should also take care of running PMD with a right click over the main/java folder and not over the project.

Comment: I do a right click on the src/main/java folder and select PMD -> Check code - the result is a progress folder with "Checking 0 out of xxx rules"....

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Eclipse Preferences -> PMD -> Rule Configuration and uncheck and recheck all the Rule Checkboxes and click the "Apply" box, does Eclipse popup the dialog box "Rules settings have changed. Do you want to do a full rebuild?"

If so, try using PMD to check this code

```
public class BadClass {
    public void badMethod() {
        try {
            String bad = "";            
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }    
}
```

That should display a lot of PMD errors. If it does not, can you find the file called pmd-eclipse.log under the Eclipse directory and post the contents?

[image: A screenshot of my PMD config]

Comment: I tried your approach but without any success. It still says checking with 0 out of xxx rules.
The file you mentioned is not there on my machine.

Comment: I want to help since I have struggled with the PMD Eclipse plug-in in the past. Can you post a screenshot of your Eclipse plug-in config? I know in the past the PMS plugin would not parse the code because of a NullPointerException in the its rules visitor.

Comment: Thanks for your screenshot. My settings look exactly the same. But I changed the path to the log file so now I can find it. There are some exceptions from non-source files (e.g. properties file or .DS_Store) but I doubt this is the reason for the problem. Which other information contained in this (large) log file could be of interest?

Comment: For me, I deleted the log to start fresh. Then I executed PMD from Eclipse. In my specific case it was one of the commenting rule choking on my JavaDoc.  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.rule.comments.AbstractCommentRule.multiLinesIn(AbstractCommentRule.java:98). So I unchecked the comment rule and PMD plug-in worked again. DO you see any Exceptions?

Comment: No, I don't see such exceptions. I see only exceptions for things like  `net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.ast.TokenMgrError: Lexical error in file .DS_Store at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "" (0), after : ""` but only for 4-5 files which are no source files. For the source files I only see things like
`DEBUG ResourceVisitor Visiting resource Block.java -
DEBUG BaseVisitor Derived files included: true - 
DEBUG BaseVisitor file Block.java is derived: false - 
DEBUG BaseVisitor file checked: true - 
DEBUG BaseVisitor Adding markerSet to accumulator for file Block.java`
but nothing more.